# How do i schedule auto svn update in linux without conflicts?

Tags: svn, cron

Since i have more than 10 linux boxes I have scheduled a cron job that updates my code base at regular interval.

It does work without any problem as long as the files dont change on the server(linux boxes). But when they do, i get conflict error. If i do the update manually i get a prompt to overwrite the changes. But since it is done via crontab i am not sure how to handle this.

I even tried --force option, but it still prompts for the action. I want the changes to be overwritten with the latest svn version.

Any idea on this?

Comment: Is SVN the right tool for this job? If you are just trying to keep files in sync across multiple boxes, perhaps rsync would be more appropriate.

Comment: Sure George, i will give it a try. I dint know about rsync before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
svn update --accept=theirs-full
```

furthermore you should consider to think about using a different tool like already mentioned rsync ...

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. Sure, I dint know about rsync. I should use it to see if it helps me over SVN.